# Storing button presses into a list and viewing them in another activity?

Tags: android, arrays, list, android-studio, button

I am new to android studio and am trying to teach myself the basics. I currently have a number of buttons for various food items (Salad Dressings). Once pressed, I want the food item to be stored in a list, so that once I go to the next activity, I can display it there showing item that was pressed.

SaladDressing.java:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class SaladDressing extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_salad_dressing);

    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BalsamicVinaigrette);
    button1.setText("Balsamic Vinaigrette");

    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Caesar);
    button2.setText("Caesar");

    Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BleuCheese);
    button3.setText("Bleu Cheese");

    Button button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.HM);
    button4.setText("Honey Mustard");

    Button button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LoCalItalian);
    button5.setText("Lo-Cal Italian");

    Button button6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CM);
    button6.setText("Chipotle Mayo");

    Button button7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Ranch);
    button7.setText("Ranch");

    Button button8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ThousandIsland);
    button8.setText("Thousand Island");

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(SaladDressing.this, Orderlist.class));
        }
    });

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(SaladDressing.this, Orderlist.class));
        }
    });

    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(SaladDressing.this, Orderlist.class));
        }
    });

    button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(SaladDressing.this, Orderlist.class));
        }
    });

    button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(SaladDressing.this, Orderlist.class));
        }
    });

    button6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(SaladDressing.this, Orderlist.class));
        }
    });

    button7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(SaladDressing.this, Orderlist.class));
        }
    });
    button8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(SaladDressing.this, Orderlist.class));
        }
    });




}
}
```

I am not sure however, how I can save those presses and display them on the Orderlist.java and layout file. I think I would have to use an ArrayList, but I'm not sure how to use it for storing button presses.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow multiple selection, then I suggest you use `CheckBoxes` instead of `Buttons`. Also, you should extend `SaladDressing` class with `View.OnClickListener` and implement `void onClick(View v)`. Then, instead of having multiple anonymous classes for each view click listener, you would have a single one and set it to all views like `button1.setOnClickListener(this);` and so on. OnClickListener method implementation could look like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            String dressing = ((Button) v).getText();
            Intent intent = new Intent(SaladDressing.this, Orderlist.class);
            intent.putExtra("selected_dressing", dressing);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, that is good advice. However, I'm still not sure how to store the values of a  button press and display it in the Orderlist class.